# Is there any VS Add-in to autoupdate XML Doc-Tags with the editing date/version?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, plugins, ide, add-in

When I change my code (methods, properties, class) I usually write manually the date and the assembly/file version in the XML Tags for documentation comments in order to remember when I edited last time (and in which version) that piece of code.

In my own projects I use the tag "version", in other projects I put edit date and assembly version in the tag "remarks".
I do this for all functions, classes, methods of my solution: of course when I have more functions in the same file and I edit the Function1, I have to notice the date/version when I edited that function and if I edit the Function2, the tag of the Function1 has not to be updated.

I was wondering if there is a VS 2010 add-in that could automate (partially too) this process.

Comment: Usually your version control system is able to do this. Upon committing the file to the repository a version and a date tag can be replaced by its value. Here the corresponding documentation of the keywords used by subversion (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)

Comment: I use svn on the NAS for the repository and TortoiseSVN to manage the files on the clients. I never looked for that feature and do not know it tortoiseSVN has somethig like that. I'll look for it. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Well, I made some tests with the Keyword Substitution and it works fine, but it is not what I'm looking for, because the substitution is related to the whole file, while I would like to tag the single functions or procedures with their own edit-date/version. If I have more functions on the same file, I would like to tag when I edited the function1, function2, and so on...